# HTTP response from rails to spring

Tags: spring, ruby-on-rails-3, http, httpresponse

From Spring framework we call an api at rails framework(rails 3.2) and get the response. Suppose the API at rails looks like:

```
def testAPI
  # generate a result called response
  render :json => response, :status => :ok
end
```

Is there any way to get status code in spring? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if we can call this api with `.json` appended to it, we can get the status showed in the response.